# Convert for loop outcome to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to create an array with 17 elements starting with 1 and other numbers are each twice the value immediately before it.

what I have so far is:

```
import numpy as np


array = np.zeros(shape=17)

array[0]=1

x = 1

for i in array:
    print(x)
    x *= 2

print(array)
```

what I got is:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

and what I want is:

```
[1.2.4.8.16.32.64.128.256.512.1024.2048.4096.8192.16384.32768.65536]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for that

```
np.logspace(0,16,17,base=2,dtype=int)
# array([    1,     2,     4,     8,    16,    32,    64,   128,   256,
#          512,  1024,  2048,  4096,  8192, 16384, 32768, 65536])
```

Alternatives:

```
1<<np.arange(17)
2**np.arange(17)
np.left_shift.accumulate(np.ones(17,int))
np.repeat((1,2),(1,16)).cumprod()
np.vander([2],17,True)[0]
np.ldexp(1,np.arange(17),dtype=float)
```

Silly alternatives:

```
from scipy.sparse import linalg,diags
linalg.spsolve(diags([(1,),(-2,)],(0,-1),(17,17)),np.r_[:17]==0    
np.packbits(np.identity(32,'?')[:17],1,'little').view('<i4').T[0] 
np.ravel_multi_index(np.identity(17,int)[::-1],np.full(17,2))
np.where(np.sum(np.ix_(*17*((0,1),))).reshape(-1)==1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value back

```
import numpy as np


array = np.zeros(shape=17, dtype="int")

x = 1

for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = x
    print(x)
    x *= 2

>>> print(array)
[    1     2     4     8    16    32    64   128   256   512  1024  2048
  4096  8192 16384 32768 65536]
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be more efficient using numpy vectorization like below.

```py
import numpy as np
n=17
triangle = (np.tri(n,n,-1, dtype=np.int64)+1)
triangle.cumprod(axis=1)[:,-1]
```

**Explanation**

`np.tri(n,n, dtype=np.int64)` will create triangle matrix with values 1 at and below diagonal and 0 else where

`np.tri(n,n, -1, dtype=np.int64)` will shift the triangle matrix by one row such that first row is all zero

`np.tri(n,n, -1, dtype=np.int64)+1` will change 0s to 1s and 1s to 2s

at last step use cumprod and take last column which is our answer as it will be products of 0,1,2 ... n 2's with remaining 1s